# Modify a "has-many through" table with Django REST framework + Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

This is kind of long and multi-part.

In Django:

I have a comic book `Issue` model and an `Ownership` model that has foreign key relations to both `Issue` and `User`. I want to allow a user ("owner") to be able to add an issue to their collection with one of three `status`es: "Have," "Want," or "Sell."

I've been advised that for the sake of a clean API, I should stick with the endpoint associated with the `Issue` and not create a new `Ownership` endpoint. That means that in Backbone, I'd have an `edit` action on the `Issue` that actually just adds or edits an `Ownership` item in Django. BTW, I don't want to allow editing the actual `Issue` model via the API **at all** yet.

Here's my `OwnershipSerializer`:

```
class OwnershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ownership
        fields = ('owner', 'status')
```

Here's the relevant parts of my `IssueSerializer`:

```
class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    owners = OwnershipSerializer(source='ownership_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = (..., 'owners')
```

I assume I'll have to go by [the documentation for writable nested representations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations), but I'm not certain how to proceed. Here's some pseudocode I've written. This will be part of the `IssueSerializer`:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    '''
    What should happen:
    - If an existing ownership exists for
      the current user, update its `status`
      with this request.
    - If there's not an existing ownership
      for this user, create a new one.

    The only data we're looking for is `status`:
    - Issue is already set.
    - User/Owner is the currently logged in user.
    '''

    # owner = self.request.user
    # try: ownership = instance.ownership
    # (check for existing ownership for this user)
        # instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        # instance.save()
        # return instance
    # except:
    # (no existing ownership for this user)
        # Ownership.objects.create(owner=owner, validated_data)
        # return issue
    pass
```

In Backbone.js:

What I'd like to end up with is updating `status` directly on an issue. Something like this (super-over-simplifed):

```
var issue = new Issue({id: id}),
    status = 'want';
issue.save({status: status});
```

Am I on the right track?